# Equation to describe dot notation

Tags: linear-algebra

Only learned what sigma notation actually was yesterday so bear with me!

Basically, dot notation can be described like this:

$$ \overline a . \overline b = (a _x * b _x) + (a _y * b _y) $$

So I was just wondering if we could describe dot notation like this:

$ n = $ Any number of vectors we want to add together

$\mathbb{R} =$ The number of real dimensions (that will be the same as the number of dimensions within those vectors)

$$\sum_i^n   (\prod_j^\mathbb{R} i _j)$$

So $ i $ cycles through each vector, and $ j $ cycles through each dimension within that vector.

Have a programming background, so I have no idea if $i$ will be 'available' inside of the $\prod$

Comment: Variable $i$ will be available inside of whole $\sum$, including interior of $\prod$.

Comment: @uraf Good to know! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot product is typically considered only as a binary operation between two vectors, and it would be defined for any dimension $n$ as 
$$\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}=\sum_{i=1}^n{a_ib_i}.$$

If you wanted to generalize the above to an $m$-ary operator sending $m$ vectors to a scalar, then your definition would work only when you switched your '$\mathbb{R}$' and '$n$' (by the way, it probably isn't best to use $\mathbb{R}$ as a variable since it is usually used to denote the real numbers).  That is, it would be given by
$$a^{\;1}\cdot a^{\;2}\cdots a^{\;m} = \sum_{i=1}^n{\prod_{j=1}^m{a_i^{\;j}}}.$$
(Note, the superscripts on the vectors aren't meant to be exponents, only a way of indexing them.)

I also want to stress that **this generalization of the dot product is not typical** (in the sense that no one uses it, and the only reason it is mentioned in this answer is because you expressed interest in generalizing it to any number of vectors.)

Comment: So if we think of this in programming terms, $a$ would be similar to an array? So we can access a certain vector by going $a _i$, as if we went `a[i]`?

Comment: Also, can we space the $ ^j $ over to the right a little bit? It would make it a lot clearer.

Comment: Yep, vectors are just finite tuples of numbers, so they would be similar to arrays, but in this case the dimensions of each of that $a^j$ must be the same for the operation to be defined.  

And if you want, sure.

Comment: @Starkers, these are just details of notation. It is not the notation that is the most important in mathematics, but the ideas it carries. If $a = (a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ then $a_k$ is simply the $k$-th coordinate of $a$. In this case it is parallel to arrays in programming (for loop aggregation). There are also parallels of foreach loop aggregation:$$\sum_{k\in A} f(k)$$ where $A$ is some set.

Comment: @Hayden Shouldn't the last vector in the sequence be $n$ not $m$?

$$a^{\;1}\cdot a^{\;2}\cdots a^{\;n} = \sum_{i=1}^n{\prod_{j=1}^m{a_i^{\;j}}}.$$

You say to swap them around in my original question..don't get that at all... Wouldn't that cause $∑$ to cycle through all of the dimensions rather than all of the vectors?

Comment: No, because the dimension is $n$, while the number of vectors we're 'dotting' is $m$.  There are $m$ first components to multiply, $m$ second components to multiply, $m$ third components to multiply, etc.  $n$ says how many components there are.

Comment: @Hayden http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814217/how-does-nested-notation-work#814220 :(

Comment: No quite sure why you had to make a new question for this, but hopefully the answer there helps you understand what I was saying?