# How does nested notation work?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is dot notation:
$$ \overline a . \overline b = (a _x * b _x) + (a _y * b _y) $$
$$ (a _x, a _y) . (b _x, b _y) = (a _x, b _x) + (a _x, b _x) $$
Here is another way to describe it with sigma notation and pi notation:

$$a^{\;1}\cdot a^{\;2}\cdots a^{\;m} = \sum_{i=1}^n{\prod_{j=1}^m{a_i^{\;j}}}.$$

$m$ **is the number of vectors we're dotting, right?**. If so I'm afraid I don't quite get it.

If $n$ is the number of vectors and $m$ the number of dimensions then I get this 100%.

But then what is the significance of the $a ^m$ and the $\prod_{}^m$? I would have thought $a^{\;1}\cdot a^{\;2}\cdots a^{\;m}$ means that $m$ is the number of vectors we're adding together, because $m$ is the last index in the sequence? And yet $m$ means the number of components? Or does $n$ always, always always magically mean the number of 'objects' in a sequence? Should the writer of the above equation then use a variable other than $m$ to signify the number of vectors? Is the following a valid and better equation?:

$d\;=\;number\;of\;components$
$$a^{\;1}\cdot a^{\;2}\cdots a^{\;n} = \sum_{i=1}^n{\prod_{j=1}^d{a_i^{\;j}}}.$$

**If so I understand completely, but please confirm. If this isn't valid, read on...**

We've got $m$ number of vectors that we're dotting. Why do we want the sigma to iterate $n$ times? I would have thought it should iterate $m$ times?

Similarly, inside each iteration of sigma, I would have said pi should iterate for the number of dimensions we have inside each vector. Instead, we're running it the number of times that we have vectors?

Have look at this notation:
$$ \overline a . \overline b . \overline c . \overline d$$

Based on the correction equation, I would have thought

- Sigma would run $n$ times. The number of dimensions. So it would run twice. Even though there are four vectors.
- Pi would run $m$ times. The number of vectors in the sequence. So it would run 4 times **each time** its 'parent' sigma is run.
- In other words, it would go through the first two vectors, and within those vectors iterate through 4 dimensions (even though each only has two)

This doesn't make any sense at all to me. This is wrong, but still makes perfect sense to me:

$$a^{\;1}\cdot a^{\;2}\cdots a^{\;m} = \sum_{i=1}^m{\prod_{j=1}^n{a_i^{\;j}}}.$$

Based on my wrong equation, I would have thought

- Sigma would run $m$ times. The number of vectors in the sequence. So it would run 4 times. Perfect.
- Pi would run $n$ times. The number of dimensions. So it would run 2 times **each time** its 'parent' sigma is run.
- In other words, it would go through all 4 of our vectors, and within those vectors iterate through all 2 of our dimensions.

That makes so much more sense. Even though it's wrong. Can anyone see where I'm coming from?
Could someone explain?

$a$ is similar to a multidimensional array in programming. So I suppose it could look something like this for two arrays:

$$a_i^{\;j} = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]$$

If we want the **z (3rd) component of the first vector**, am I right in thinking we do this: $$ a_1^{\;3} $$

Well if we're all agreed $m$ should be the number of vectors, that means the $j$ iterator could never get higher than the number of vectors in the sequence: 
$\prod_{j=1}^m $ If $m$ is the number of vectors (there are 2), j will never get higher than 2.

So we can't do this:

$ a_1^{\;3} $ or this:  $ a_2^{\;3} $

Apparently. Surely someone out there can see what I mean.

Does this mean $i$ is the index for each component and $j$ is the index for the vector? That feels so illogical and wrong. Never mind that it makes so sense.

Comment: The dot product is a very particular thing.  I feel like you're trying to generalize it into something having to do with sums and involving a lot of vectors.  And hey, you can define what you want of course, but the dot product as typically presented is just an operation on two vectors.  That's all that's needed to get across the notions of lengths of vectors and angles between vectors that we see in Euclidean geometry.

Comment: @Muphrid Thanks Murphid, I'm sure you're right, but I just want to tame scary looking equations in my own head :) I just want it to be valid. I've updated my question. Could you read the fifth paragraph please and confirm that equation?

Comment: Sorry, it's not apparent to me what it is you want to do.  I thought you wanted to multiply each vector compoenent-wise, generating a new vector with the same dimensions, and then sum all the components of that vector to get a single result.  But I think you've put so much information in the question about *trying* to understand that it's no longer clear to me what you want to *do*.

Comment: No worries I understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing it out *without* $\Sigma$s or $\Pi$s, with actual numbers, where the number of components in the vectors is not equal to the number of vectors there are, and you will see what's going on.

For example, consider $m=2$ and $n=3$, so the usual dot product:

$$(a_1,a_2,a_3)\cdot(b_1,b_2,b_3)=a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3.$$

Does the number of summands equal the number of (a) vectors, or (b) components? What about the number of factors being multiplied for each summand?

In other news, I don't think I've seen this $m$-ary dot product you're referring to.

Comment: So m is our number of vectors, n is our number of dimensions?

Comment: 2 vectors so we should add them together using Σ. 3 components so we need to times them using Π. And yet the 3 goes over the Σ and the 2 goes over the Π. ??

Comment: @Starkers How many summands does $a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3$ have? It has three. You're adding three things together. So the sigma has a three over it. In each of the three summands, $a_1b_1$, $a_2b_2$, $a_3b_3$, how many things are being multiplied together? Two things. You're multiplying two things together. So the $\Pi$ has a two over it. $$a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3=\sum_{i=1}^{\color{Red}3} a_i b_i.$$ Perhaps you should go back and review what summation is.

Comment: Thanks...my problem was not understanding dot product (talking about running before walking!)!